# iPhone UIWebView - Calling loadHTMLString:baseURL: a second time doesn't do anything?

Tags: iphone, html, uiwebview, load

Is the `-loadHTMLString:baseURL:` method of UIWebView meant to only be called once per instance?

Here's my logic flow:

```
1.  View loads & supplies UIWebView placeholder text via -loadHTMLString:baseURL:
2.  NSURLConnection requests a URL asynchronously
3.  Upon NSURLConnection finished, replace UIWebView content with loaded data 
    via -loadHTMLString:baseURL:
```

Debugging shows that `loadHTMLString:baseURL:` is being called and the string being passed in is correct, but the UIWebView isn't updated.  I even tried calling [webViewInstance setNeedsDisplay] thinking a redraw would fix it, but no dice.

In Apple Developer docs, it says nothing about the method being one-call-per-instance, but based on its behavior, this is what it seems like.  Anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no limit on the number of times loadHTMLString: can be called. I call it hundreds of times on the same UIWebView in my app.

Did you implement webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: ? If you did, make sure you return YES.

Comment: well don't I feel foolish now ... I added some logic to intercept requests a couple of weeks ago and forgot about it.  Thanks for taking the time to reply :)