# UIWebView takes time to loads

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am working on the IOS app. In the app I have a web view in which I am showing some html content like hyperlinks.  But the web view loads very slowly. It takes time only when I load the web view first time. I am writing the content in the UITextView and then adding this textView on the webView and web view is added on the viewController.

I am  writing the code like this:-

```
UIWebView *webView= [[UIWebView alloc ]init];

webView.frame=CGRectMake(180,210,self.view.frame.size.width-20,470);   

UITextView *sampletext=[[UITextview alloc]init];

sampletext.frame=CGRectMake(0,50,webView.frame.size.width-50, 260);

sampletext.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.<a href = ‘#’>Duis </a>aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
<a href=‘#’>Lorem ipsum</a>dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</body></html>”];

[webView loadHTMLString:sampletext.text baseURL:nil];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

How to handle this issue. I will be thankful if anybody help me.

Thanks

Comment: see so answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034433/uiwebview-taking-too-much-of-time-to-load-html-content-in-ios-7

Comment: Please try this <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086188/iphone-uiwebview-calling-loadhtmlstringbaseurl-a-second-time-doesnt-do-anyt>

Comment: why are you using UITextView?I dont get it, you can just create a string and load that html string in webView,no need of uiTextView.

Answer (score 0):

If you're supporting iOS 7 only (and even if you're not consider this implementation for the iOS 7 version of the app), you can use just UITextView and attributed strings like so:

```
NSString *html = @"<bold>Wow!</bold> Now <em>iOS</em> can create <h3>NSAttributedString</h3> from HTMLs!";
NSDictionary *options = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType};

NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:options documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

self.textView.attributedText = attrString;
```

Going from a UIWebView to this in my app sped up loading and scrolling a great deal on iOS 7.